# How do I prove that the typical fibre of the associated bundle $(P_F:=(P\times F)/\sim_G,\pi_F,M)$ is $F$?

Tags: differential-geometry, equivalence-relations, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

I want to show that the typical fibre of the associated bundle $(P_F,\pi_F,M)$ is $F$.

**Set-up:** Consider a principal $G$-bundle $(P,\pi,M)$ with $\pi:P\rightarrow M$. Let $F$ be a smooth manifold equipped with a left $G$-action and construct the associated bundle $(P_F,\pi_F,M)$ by defining $$P_F:=(P\times F)/\sim_G$$ where $(p',f')\sim_G(p,f):\iff \exists g\in G: p'=p\triangleleft g : f'=g^{-1}\triangleright f$ and

$$\begin{alignat*}{2}
\pi_{F}:P_F&\longrightarrow M \\
[(p,f)]&\longmapsto \pi_F([(p,f)]):=\pi(p)
\end{alignat*}$$

**My attempt:** I've tried to simply use the definition of a bundle's fibre to see what comes out the other end:

$$
\text{Fibre}_x:=\text{preim}_{\pi_F}(\{x\}) \\
=\{[(p,f)]\in P_F \mid \pi_F([(p,f)])=x\} \\
=\{\{(p',f')\in P\times F \mid \exists g\in G: p'=p\triangleleft g : f'=g^{-1}\triangleright f\} \mid \pi(p)=x\}
$$
but now I'm stuck. I was hoping (perhaps with a lot of wishful thinking) that I could get rid of the elements of $P$ somehow and be left with something like "$\text{Fibre}_x=\{f\}=F$", but this doesn't look at all likely. A possible (?) next step could be that $p'=p\triangleleft g \iff \pi(p)=\pi(p')=x$ and so I could maybe get rid of one of these conditions...? Though I'm not sure how much that would help.  Any push in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Reduce to the case where $P=M\times G$. What do you get for the equivalence class of $(m,e,f)$ as $f$ varies over $F$?

Comment: Hm, I'm not quite sure I understand. Is $(m,e,f)\in M\times G\times F$ here? How do we identify elements of this space given that there is no group action defined on $M$?

Comment: The $G$-action is trivial on $M$, by right multiplication on itself. (We're trivializing the principal bundle, after all.)

Comment: I see, so we have something like $[(m,e,f)]=\{(m',e',f')\mid \exists g\in G :m'=m\triangleleft g : e'=e\triangleleft g : f'=g^{-1}\triangleright f\}$?

Comment: No, I said $m=m’$, and remember that $e$ denotes the identity element of a group.

Comment: Ok, so since $e'=e\triangleleft g = g$ and $f'=g^{-1}\triangleright f = e'\triangleright f = f$, then we have $[(m,e,f)]=\{(m',e',f')\in M\times G \times F \mid \exists g \in G: m'=m : e'=e=g : f' = f\}$. Is that more on the right track?

Comment: It looks like we can write this particular equivalence class as $[(m,e,f)]=M\times \{e\}\times F$ (Possibly? I'm not sure if that's legitimate..). That relies on the fact that we are considering an equivalence class that involves the identity element of the group, so I'm not sure how this applies to the case involving the equivalence class $[(p,f)]$ in my original question. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: What you wrote doesn't quite make sense. The *set* of all equivalence classes will in fact be $M\times\{e\}\times F$, which shows you have a bundle with fiber $F$ — working in general with a local trivialization, rather than assuming that $P$ is globally trivial.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought that a bundle is trivial and has fiber $F$ if the total space is $M\times F$, rather than $M\times\{e\}\times F$. How do I go from $P_F$ being the set of all equivalence classes $[(p,f)]$ to involving the group in the equivalence class (if indeed you are saying that to solve the problem I need to show $P_F=M\times \{e\}\times F$)? As I'm sure is obvious, I'm rather unsure about all of this, so apologies if I'm misunderstanding.